# Packer virtualbox-vm export with different filename

Tags: virtualbox, packer, ova

I'm using Packer to export existing VirtualBox VM to ova, but could not find how to specify a filename for that ova.

Config looks like this:

```
  "builders": [{
  "type": "virtualbox-vm",
  "vm_name": "base-vm",
  "output_directory": "output-ova",
  "format": "ova",
  ...
```

In the output I got `output-ova/base-vm.ova`. Desired output is something like `output-ova/exported-vm.ova`.
Option `vm-name` controls both name of the existing VM and the name of the exported file.

So, how do I set a different name for the output file?

Answer (score 1):

did you try something with

```
  "builders": [{
      "type": "virtualbox-vm",
      "vm_name": "base-vm",
      "output_directory": "output-ova",
      "format": "ova",
      "export_opts":
      [
          "--output", "exported-vm.ova",
      ],
      ...
```

Comment: Where this information came from? Official docs say:
--output/-o: Specifies the short name of the cloud service provider to which you export. For Oracle Cloud Infrastructure, enter OCI://.

Comment: comes from trial :) I've been using VBoxManage tool for some times before

Comment: Actually that --output works, but in case of packer, it is not. Syntax error: You can only specify --output once.
Looks like packer itself uses it.

Comment: then packer must define the output value itself and not sure we can re-use, I think it will be an issue against packer directly